# Add texfield in runtime in IOS

Tags: ios7

I want to make an "add" button to add as many textfields as i want in my scroll view.

I did this already

```
UITextField *text=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,200)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:text];
```

But is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working?  If you run this repeatedly, you'll stack views and it will look like one because they all have the same frame.

Comment: But not even one appears...

Comment: Is your add btn receiving touch? Have you added an action event?  Have you NSLogged this action event to make sure this method is actually running?

Comment: Yes, it logs. I also tried with a button and works. Look:     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.mainScroll addSubview:button];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your complete button code:

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
 [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
 button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0); 

 // add this
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 // continue

 [self.mainScroll addSubview:button];
```

Then add this somewhere:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    UITextField *text=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,200,200)];
    text.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // just to make sure it's showing up.
    [self.scrollView addSubview:text];
}
```

Comment: Thats no my button code. What i tried to say is that my button add works adding more button like that one you posted. But doesnt for texfields.
Anyway, the backgorund color did the trick, becasue it was creating transparen texfields without borders so i couldn see it.

Comment: So, buttonPressed is running, but no text field is added?

Comment: Yes! With backgroun color now i can see it!

Comment: I had a feeling it was that, I've definitely done it before! Glad I added that extra line.

Answer (score 0):

First create common function like this,

```
-(void)setTextfieldStyle:(UITextField *)pTmpTextField
{
    pTmpTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    pTmpTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    pTmpTextField.placeholder = @"First Name";
    pTmpTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    pTmpTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    pTmpTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    pTmpTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    pTmpTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
    pTmpTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

and use this for creating UITextFiled,

```
int y = 0;
for(int i=0;i < 5;i++)
{
UITextField *txtTemp=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 300, 31)];
txtTemp.tag = i;
[self setTextfieldStyle:txtTemp];
[self.view addSubview:txtTemp];
[txtTemp release];
y+=36;
}
```

This is UITextField's delegate method,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
}
```

Hope this works for you as this works for me. only keep this in mind that add the text fields to your scroll view. 
In the example am adding them to my view!